# Reactjs Syntax problem: Unexpected token under let jsonLang

Tags: reactjs

I have tried countless googling and trouble shooting. I am following a tutorial online and in the tutorial they use this kind of syntax (where the javascript code is below the constructor and above the render.

```
export default class NewFormDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            validated: false,
            language: 'en',
            siteName: null,
            counties: null,
            siteAddress: null,
            siteEmail: null,
            siteNumber: null,
            siteCat: null,
            openTimes: null,
            fees: null,
            access: null,
            gps: null,
            w3w: null,
            textHeader: null,
            textContent: null
        };
    }

    let jsonLang;

    if (this.state.language == 'en') {
        jsonLang = data.en;
    } else if (this.state.language == 'es') {
        jsonLang = data.es;
    } else {
        jsonLang = data.en;
    }

    const placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
    const counties = jsonLang.counties;

    const handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                {/* General Information */}
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder={placeholders.siteName}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input className="form-control" type="select" id="counties" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled value={placeholders.siteCounties} selected>{placeholders.siteCounty}</option>
                            { counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteAddress" placeholder={placeholders.siteAdd} id="siteAddress" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="email" name="siteEmail" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteEmail" placeholder={placeholders.email} />
                    </Col> 
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="tel" name="siteNumber" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteNumber" placeholder={placeholders.number}/>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="select" name="siteCat" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteCat" multiple placeholder={placeholders.categories}>
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled selected>{placeholders.categories}</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="openTimes" onChange={this.handleChange} id="openTimes" placeholder={placeholders.times} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="fees" onChange={this.handleChange} id="fees" placeholder={placeholders.fees}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="access" onChange={this.handleChange} id="access" placeholder={placeholders.access} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                {/* Location Information */}
                <FormGroup row> 
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="gps" onChange={this.handleChange} id="gps" placeholder={placeholders.gps}/>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="w3w" id="w3w" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder={placeholders.w3w} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txtHeader" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtHeader" placeholder={placeholders.textHeader} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txtContent" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtContent" placeholder={placeholders.textContent} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check row>
                    <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                        <Link to="/newSite/tours"><Button className="btn-primary">Tours &rarr;</Button></Link>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup> 
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error: `Unexpected token under let jsonLang;`.

Please help! I have tried adding/removing braces, semi-colons etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code inside a class definition needs to be inside a [class method](https://javascript.info/class#only-methods) for it to be valid. If you want something to run everytime an object is instantiated you can write said instructions inside the constructor or in a method that gets called within said constructor:

```
export default class NewFormDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          validated: false,
          language: 'en',
          siteName: null,
          counties: null,
          siteAddress: null,
          siteEmail: null,
          siteNumber: null,
          siteCat: null,
          openTimes: null,
          fees: null,
          access: null,
          gps: null,
          w3w: null,
          textHeader: null,
          textContent: null
      };

      let jsonLang;

      if (this.state.language == 'en') {
          jsonLang = data.en;
      } else if (this.state.language == 'es') {
          jsonLang = data.es;
      } else {
          jsonLang = data.en;
      }

      this.placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
      this.counties = jsonLang.counties;
  }

  handleChange = e => {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
      console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
              {/* General Information */}
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder={this.placeholders.siteName}/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input className="form-control" type="select" id="counties" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                          <option className="selectDefault" disabled value={this.placeholders.siteCounties} selected>{this.placeholders.siteCounty}</option>
                          { this.counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                      </Input>
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={12}>
                      <Input type="textarea" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteAddress" placeholder={this.placeholders.siteAdd} id="siteAddress" />
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="email" name="siteEmail" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteEmail" placeholder={this.placeholders.email} />
                  </Col> 
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="tel" name="siteNumber" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteNumber" placeholder={this.placeholders.number}/>
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="select" name="siteCat" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteCat" multiple placeholder={this.placeholders.categories}>
                          <option className="selectDefault" disabled selected>{this.placeholders.categories}</option>
                          <option value="">1</option>
                          <option value="">1</option>
                          <option value="">1</option>
                          <option value="">1</option>
                      </Input>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="text" name="openTimes" onChange={this.handleChange} id="openTimes" placeholder={this.placeholders.times} />
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="textarea" name="fees" onChange={this.handleChange} id="fees" placeholder={this.placeholders.fees}/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="text" name="access" onChange={this.handleChange} id="access" placeholder={this.placeholders.access} />
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <hr/>
              {/* Location Information */}
              <FormGroup row> 
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="text" name="gps" onChange={this.handleChange} id="gps" placeholder={this.placeholders.gps}/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={6}>
                      <Input type="text" name="w3w" id="w3w" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder={this.placeholders.w3w} />
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <hr/>
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={12}>
                      <Input type="textarea" name="txtHeader" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtHeader" placeholder={this.placeholders.textHeader} />
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup row>
                  <Col sm={12}>
                      <Input type="textarea" name="txtContent" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtContent" placeholder={this.placeholders.textContent} />
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup>
              <FormGroup check row>
                  <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                      <Link to="/newSite/tours"><Button className="btn-primary">Tours &rarr;</Button></Link>
                  </Col>
              </FormGroup> 
          </Form>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but now my handleSubmit method doesn't work haha

Comment: Right. I think you need to bind those methods. Try adding `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`  and `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`in the constructor.

Comment: nope didn't work, the handleChange method works fine, but the handleSubmit doesnt. I also added `value="submit"` to the button at the end of the form

Comment: You'll need to be more concise... What error is it giving you?

Comment: Its ok I got it. It wasnt giving me an error. Turns out the handleSubmit method was executing but the page was refreshing instantly after so I couldnt see the console.log work. Fixed it using preventDefault() in the handleSubmit method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good! I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You made an error with the enclosing "}". Now you are outside the constructor method and can only write plain JavaScript meaning that you can define variables using "var"

var jsonLang = 'en'

or you put the logic after the setState

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        validated: false,
        language: 'en',
        siteName: null,
        counties: null,
        siteAddress: null,
        siteEmail: null,
        siteNumber: null,
        siteCat: null,
        openTimes: null,
        fees: null,
        access: null,
        gps: null,
        w3w: null,
        textHeader: null,
        textContent: null
    };

let jsonLang;


if (this.state.language == 'en') {
    jsonLang = data.en;
} else if (this.state.language == 'es') {
    jsonLang = data.es;
} else {
    jsonLang = data.en;
}

const placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
const counties = jsonLang.counties;
}
```

Comment: If I do this, and keep the 2 methods outside of the contructor, I get the error `placeholders is not defined`

Comment: Here is the tutorial I am referencing https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-login-page.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your render() method is outside of constructor() range block.

Should be:

```
export default class NewFormDetails extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            validated: false,
            language: 'en',
            siteName: null,
            counties: null,
            siteAddress: null,
            siteEmail: null,
            siteNumber: null,
            siteCat: null,
            openTimes: null,
            fees: null,
            access: null,
            gps: null,
            w3w: null,
            textHeader: null,
            textContent: null
        };
    }

    render()
    {
        let jsonLang;

        if (this.state.language == 'en')
        {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        } else if (this.state.language == 'es')
        {
            jsonLang = data.es;
        } else
        {
            jsonLang = data.en;
        }

        const placeholders = jsonLang.placeholders;
        const counties = jsonLang.counties;

        const handleChange = e =>
        {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }

        const handleSubmit = () =>
        {
            console.log(this.state);
        }

        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                {/* General Information */}
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder={placeholders.siteName} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input className="form-control" type="select" id="counties" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled value={placeholders.siteCounties} selected>{placeholders.siteCounty}</option>
                            {counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" onChange={this.handleChange} name="siteAddress" placeholder={placeholders.siteAdd} id="siteAddress" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="email" name="siteEmail" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteEmail" placeholder={placeholders.email} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="tel" name="siteNumber" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteNumber" placeholder={placeholders.number} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="select" name="siteCat" onChange={this.handleChange} id="siteCat" multiple placeholder={placeholders.categories}>
                            <option className="selectDefault" disabled selected>{placeholders.categories}</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                            <option value="">1</option>
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="openTimes" onChange={this.handleChange} id="openTimes" placeholder={placeholders.times} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="fees" onChange={this.handleChange} id="fees" placeholder={placeholders.fees} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="access" onChange={this.handleChange} id="access" placeholder={placeholders.access} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr />
                {/* Location Information */}
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="gps" onChange={this.handleChange} id="gps" placeholder={placeholders.gps} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={6}>
                        <Input type="text" name="w3w" id="w3w" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder={placeholders.w3w} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr />
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txtHeader" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtHeader" placeholder={placeholders.textHeader} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txtContent" onChange={this.handleChange} id="txtContent" placeholder={placeholders.textContent} />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check row>
                    <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                        <Link to="/newSite/tours"><Button className="btn-primary">Tours &rarr;</Button></Link>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsonLang;
const language = 'ss' ;

 if (this.language == 'ss') {
       jsonLang = language.data;
   console.log(jsonLang);

    } else {
      jsonLang = language.data;
        console.log(language);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for how this fixes the OP's issue? Doing so will not just help the OP, it will help others learn how to avoid similar issues. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

let jsonLang = 'en';

have a goodday